# What Netflix OSS frameworks can I use on-premise?

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix, netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix-zuul

I have looked at the different frameworks in the Netflix OSS stack, but I have problems find which of those have a strong dependency to AWS. E.g. some pages state that Eureka can only be used on AWS, but Eureka's own pages does not clearly state this. I would be interested in knowing whether the following tools have strong AWS dependency:

```
- Zuul
- Ribbon
- Eureka
- Hystrix
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Only looked at ribbon and hystrix at the moment : no dependency on aws

Comment: All of those that you list are available in Spring Cloud and don't require AWS. I have them all running locally together on a test standalone Linux laptop.

Comment: None of the tools you have mentioned have any dependency on AWS. Though, due to very nature of microservices, they are best used on cloud infrastructure.